# add simple 7 second delay before javascript variable is called custom modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like for the below variable to fire after a 7 second delay. My chaining attempt failed.

```
$(function(){ 
    var inst = $.remodal.lookup[$('[data-remodal-id=modal]').data('remodal')];
    inst.open();
});
```

Attempt:

```
    inst.delay(7000).open();
```

Comment: Yip that'll do it http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp. 

along the lines of:

setTimeout(function() { inst.open(); }, 7000);

or

setTimeout("inst.open", 7000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a `setTimeout`

```
$(function(){ 
    var inst = $.remodal.lookup[$('[data-remodal-id=modal]').data('remodal')];
    setTimeout(function(){
        inst.open();
    }, 7000); // 7000 ms = 7 seconds
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm thinking this is simpler than it actually is, but couldn't you just wrap the piece you wish to delay inside a setTimeout()?

```
setTimeout(function() {
     inst.open();
}, 7000);
```